Finding the general solution of a 1st order PDE from its complete solution involving 2 arbitrary constants.
While studying about PDEs I found that we can calculate the general solution of a PDE from it's complete solution.
The method goes like this:
If say, a PDE $F(x,y,z,p,q)=0$ where $p=z_x,q=z_y$ is given, and $f(x,y,z,a,b)=0$ is a complete solution of $F,$ then assume $b$ to be an unknown function of $a$ say, $b=\phi(a).$
So, the complete solution $f$ becomes, $f(x,y,z,a,\phi(a))=0\tag 1$
Now, differentiating the above equation wrt $a$ we get, $f_a(x,y,z,a,\phi(a))+f_b(x,y,z,a,\phi(a))\phi'(a)=0\tag 2$
In principle we can solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get $a=a(x,y,z).$
Substituting this in $(1)$ we have,
$f(x,y,z,a(x,y,z),\phi(a(x,y,z))=0.$ This is precisely the general solution of the given PDE as, $b$ is an arbitrary function of $a.$

Now, I wanted to implement this method using an example. So, suppose we have a PDE $z=pq$ having a complete solution $z=(x+a)(y+b).$
Now, proceeding in line of the above method, let $b=\phi(a).$
So, the complete solution becomes $z=(x+a)(y+\phi(a)).$
Differentiating the above equation wrt $a,$ we have,
$$0=(x+a)\phi'(a)+(y+\phi(a))$$
So, we have got $z=(x+a)(y+\phi(a))$ and $x\phi'(a)+a\phi'(a)+y+\phi(a)=0$ as the two equations.
But I don't know how to solve for $a$ such that $a=a(x,y,z)$ from the last two equations.
This makes me doubt about the validity of the method I described earlier for $(2)$ always has an unknown term (or function) $\phi(a)$ due to which finding $a=a(x,y,z)$ does not seem to be feasible at all.
Any help regarding these issues will be greatly appreciated.
